# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Cost

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-.net, azure-scheduler

I'm using azure data factory for some migration project. while doing it I came a cross with some clarification. I just want to know if I keep a pipeline in ADF without using it will there be a cost for that? I need to run some pipelines according to a schedule like weekly or monthly. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to know if I keep a pipeline in ADF without using it will
>   there be a cost for that?

Quick answer is NO. Based on [ADF pricing document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/),the billing consists of `Data pipelines` and `SQL Server Integration Services`.

Your account only need to pay when you execute your activities(in the pipelines). Or it is related to migration of SQL Server DB.

[image]

Comment: Clarification question -- what is an "activity run" exactly? -- Is it a flat rate for an activity that's run once? -- What if the activity is transforming petabytes of data? -- Surely there is a higher cost?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $0.80 / month / inactive pipeline. According to [Data Pipeline Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/), under the heading *Inactive pipelines*,

> A pipeline is considered inactive if it has no associated trigger or any runs within the month. An inactive pipeline is charged at $0.80 per month.

Comment: I think the above statement is true for ADF v01 (available at same page you shared). Not sure about ADF v02 though)
EDIT: Grammar.